# Excel [VBA] Select Column within Table and insert data to empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table where sometimes there is data missing in the Column G (7th).

So far I selected a range in this column with my mouse and then ran this macro to fill empty cells with "No Data":

```
Sub FillEmptyCell()  
Dim cell As Range  
Dim InputValue As String  
For Each cell In Selection  
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then  
    cell.Value = "No Data"  
    End If  
Next  
End Sub
```

However data in that column keeps getting more and I would like to **automatically select the entire table range of the 7th column** and **fill empty cells with "No Data".**

**How do I implement this?**

Comment: I thnk you're asking about running this macro without selecting first. In which case `Set MyRange = Range("G1", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` should do the trick. Then use `myRange` instead of `Selection` in your code

Comment: thanks, thats working just fine, too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("G1:G" & lr)

For Each cell In Rng
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        cell.Value = "No Data"
    End If
Next
```